# Sort of NDIS Intermediate Miniport on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, ethernet, kernel-extension

We have a solution of an intermediate network layer which is currently implemented as a NDIS IM on Windows. I am investigating how this thing could be ported to Mac OS X.

Ideally, it should be an intermediate driver/kext right on top of the ethernet-capable adapter, and below any IP/ARP/whatsoever, operating only with ethernet frames.

Some tutorial/sample would be preferred, something like the passthru sample from the WDK, although any hints would be appreciated.

No, this is not a filter/firewall, it's not vpn, it's a completely new and quite complicated intermediate layer operating at that level.

Comment: It would probably help to know what kind of operations it should be able to do? Bear in mind that OSX kernel experts might not be Windows kernel experts, so Windows-specific terms like "NDIS" or "Miniport" don't mean a lot.

Comment: it should be able to get packets sent down by the above layers (process them and wrap in its own packets, then send them down), indicate packets to the above layers (dewrap what it received from below), as well as being able to discuss itself with others like him on the same ethernet segment (via its own custom ethertype). also should be able to tell the above layers what is its MTU size, to make room for its own wrapping procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to read [Network Kernel Extensions Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/NKEConceptual/intro/intro.html). See NKE architecture in "Network Kernel Extensions Overview" section. Looks like you need an [Interface Filter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/NKEConceptual/interface_filter_nke/interface_filter_nke.html) or may be even a [virtual interface](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/NKEConceptual/interface_nke/interface_nke.html).
Also see the "Networking" chapter (chapter 13) in the "OS X and iOS Kernel Programming" book (by Ole Henry Halvorsen and Douglas Clarke). As far as I remember there was an example of simple ethernet controller driver.

Comment: the book is a good reference, because i need some general wisdom too. thanks!

Comment: i've read the first 5 chapters or so of this book... it puts a lot of emphasis on writing *hardware* drivers specifically, so it'll be 90% waste of time for me. yet not clear where my purely-software abstraction layer should go, given that the kernel has 3 parts. i feel like it'll be as in this anecdote: - wife, where's the salt? - you idiot, the salt is in the sugar box that has "coffee" written on it!

Comment: Well, my advice was about Network chapter of the book. There are 7 chapters left until you'll get there ;) For the general understanding read the NKE Programming Guide first. It will help you to decide where your driver should be

Comment: well, my personal impression is that i should go to Mach driver junctions (at least that seems how they are called), alltogether below the bsd subsystem. after all, ndis on windows is also entirely below its "bsd"/tcpip part. so, NKE seems to be a missed assumption, but the final conclusion will be after i finish the book.

Comment: after all, i said we are not a vpn, not a filter/firewall, although we have some characteristics of the both. but we should be compatible and able to coexist with any possible type of vpn or filter/firewall that users would want to have on their systems. so, we prefer to leave the bsd part to them so they could hook there as usual, and we do our job completely transparently to them, much the same as we currently do on windows.

Comment: Ok. Read the Kernel Programming Guide - it is more general